# angular select defualt option not displaying

Tags: angular, select, default-value

I have these selects and they are not showing the default option, they just show empty at the beginning.

```
<label>Review Type</label>
    <select clrSelect name="reviewerTypes" (change)="onChange(currentReviewerType)" 
      [(ngModel)]="currentReviewerType">
        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>
            Choose value
        </option>
        <option *ngFor="let reviewType of reviewerTypes" [(ngValue)]="reviewType">
            {{reviewType.reviewType}}
        </option>
</select>
<label>Reviewer</label>
<select clrSelect name="options" [(ngModel)]="currentReviewer">
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose value</option>
    <option *ngFor="let reviewer of reviewers" [(ngValue)]="reviewer">
        {{reviewer.user}}
    </option>
</select>
```

ts file:

```
reviewerTypes: [] = [];
reviewers: [] = [];
reviewersAdded: any[] = [];
currentReviewer;
currentReviewerType;
defaultType = {id:0, reviewType:"Choose Value"};
defaultReviewer = {userId:0,user:"Choose Value"};;

constructor(private dataService: DataServicesService) { }
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.GetReviewerTypes().subscribe( response => this.reviewerTypes = response, error 
        => console.log(error));
    this.currentReviewer = this.defaultType;////i tried to add a default object, didn't work
    this.currentReviewer = this.defaultReviewer;
}

onChange(selection){
    let reviewerId = selection;
    this.dataService.GetReviewersByType(reviewerId.id).subscribe( (response)=> {
      this.reviewers = response
      this.currentReviewer = this.defaultReviewer;
    }, 
    error => console.log(error));
}
```

I already tried `[ngValue]="null"`, `[selected]="true"` and `**[ngValue]="null" disabled**` with this one i get an error of can't bind it since it's an unknowed property.

The problem is with both, the normal select, and the dynamic one too.

I'm not sure what else could I do.

Comment: Did you try `[ngValue]="undefined"`? What is the initial value of `currentReviewerType`? I don't see that property in your code.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I edited the question to add them, the `undefined` worked! for the dynamic one is there a way to `onChange` of is values to reset it to the default option?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean exactly. You can set `currentReviewerType = undefined` to select the default option again.

Comment: @ConnorsFan that worked too! thanks, man that was really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as @ConnorsFan mentioned in a comment above. Since I'm binding the `select` with an object adding `[ngValue]="undefined` showed the default value, and for the dynamic `select` assigning it undefined on the `onChange` also displays the default value when the first one changes.

ts.

```
onChange(selection){
    let reviewerId = selection;
    this.dataService.GetReviewersByType(reviewerId.id).subscribe( (response)=> {
      this.reviewers = response
      this.currentReviewer = undefined;////////////Assign undefined
    }, 
    error => console.log(error));
}
```

Html.

```
<select clrSelect name="reviewerTypes" (change)="onChange(currentReviewerType)" 
[(ngModel)]="currentReviewerType">
    <option [ngValue]="undefined" selected disabled>
        Choose value
    </option>
    <option *ngFor="let reviewType of reviewerTypes" [(ngValue)]="reviewType">
        {{reviewType.reviewType}}
    </option>
</select>

<select clrSelect name="options" [(ngModel)]="currentReviewer" >
    <option [ngValue]="undefined" selected disabled hidden>Choose value</option>
    <option *ngFor="let reviewer of reviewers" [(ngValue)]="reviewer">
        {{reviewer.user}}
    </option>
</select>
```